# How to show childActivity with databinding that extends BaseActivity?

Tags: android, data-binding, layout-inflater

I am using a base activity as a parent of another activity "RecicpeActivity" as I have overridden the method setContentView in the base activity so that the child activity can use it and pass its layout to be inflated in the frame layout.
The Child activity "RecicpeActivity" uses DataBinding to set its views.
What I am doing is I am trying to inflate the layout of the child activity into a frame layout "container" in the base activity BUT the data binding is not being considered at all as I am having a white screen even though I have seen  the layout of the child activity as a child of the frame layout while debugging.

- I have tried two ways:

1- The first one I have tried to pass the layout of the child activity simply by calling setContentView and inflated the passed layout to the frame layout in the base activity.

2- The second on I have tried to use data binding in the base activity, But I don't think it would matter.

_ChildActivity

```
public class RecipeActivity extends BaseActivity {
private ActivityRecipeBinding mBinding;
private static final String RECIPE_INTENT_KEY = "recipe key";
private ScrollView mScrollView;
private RecipeViewModel recipeViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    recipeViewModel = 
          ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RecipeViewModel.class);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                getLayoutInflater(), 
                R.layout.activity_recipe, null, false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

    // This method is implemented in the BaseActivity.
    showProgressBar(true);
    recipeViewModel.getRecipe().observe(this, new Observer<Recipe>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Recipe recipe) {
            if (recipe != null){
                if (recipe.getRecipe_id().equals(
                    recipeViewModel.getRecipeId())){
                    mBinding.setRecipe(recipe);
                    mScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    showProgressBar(false);

                }
            }
        }
    });
    recipeViewModel.getRecipeById(getIncomingIntentRecipeId());
}

private String getIncomingIntentRecipeId(){
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(RECIPE_INTENT_KEY)){
        String recipe_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(RECIPE_INTENT_KEY);
        return recipe_id;
    }
    return null;
}
```

_BaseActivity

```
 public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout  = 
       (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
          R.layout.activity_base, null);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = mRelativeLayout.findViewById(
          R.id.activity_content);
        mProgressBar = mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)

        /**
         * True means layoutResID should be inflated and made a part of
            parent frameLayout
         */
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
        super.setContentView(mRelativeLayout);
    }

    public void showProgressBar(boolean visibility){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(visibility ?
                  View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

_ChildActivity Layout "activity_recipe"

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <data>
            <variable
                name="recipe"
                type="com.mustafa.foodapp.models.Recipe" />

            <import type="com.mustafa.foodapp.util.StringUtils" />
        </data>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/recipe_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/recipe_image_height"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    app:imageUrl="@{recipe.image_url}" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recipe_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/recipe_image"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:text="@{recipe.title}"

                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/recipe_title_text_size" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/recipe_title"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="100">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/recipe_social_score"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@{String.valueOf(
                                 Math.round(recipe.social_rank))}"
                        android:textColor="@color/red"

                        android:textSize="@dimen/
                            recipe_publisher_text_size"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ingredients_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/container"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@{StringUtils.getStringIngredients(
                                          recipe.ingredients)}" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </layout>
```

_BaseActivity Layout "activity_base"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/base_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

_BaseActivity with data-binding "2nd way"

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public ProgressBar mProgressBar;
public ActivityBaseBinding baseBinding;

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

      baseBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.activity_base,  null, false);
      mProgressBar = baseBinding.progressBar;

    /**
     * True means layoutResID should be inflated and made a part of the 
                      parent frameLayout
     */
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, baseBinding.activityContent, 
                                                                      true);
    super.setContentView(baseBinding.getRoot());
}

public void showProgressBar(boolean visibility){
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(visibility ?
                       View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `layout.requestLayout()` after inflating so it can adjust to the changes made after inflating.

```java
 getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, baseBinding.activityContent, true);
 mRelativeLayout.requestLayout();
 super.setContentView(baseBinding.getRoot());
```

> public void requestLayout ()
>   Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree.

If you can see the child in view heirarchy while debugging, then this should fix the issue.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()

**PART 2**: Binding Doesn't work

You are inflating view two times, once in your child activity, and once in your BaseActivity:

```
  mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                getLayoutInflater(), 
                R.layout.activity_recipe, null, false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);
```

mBinding You inflated once for databinding, then you passed layout id to setContentView where it inflated again:

```
 getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
```

So the one in Databinding is a different view from the one you added to base layout.

**Create an Overloaded version of setContentView that accepts view instead of id.**

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried it but it didn't work, I am actually able to see the inflated layout as a child of the frame Layout but data-binding doesn't work in it for some reason.

Comment: @MustafaShahoud I noticed that it wouldn't work, I thought you would figure out why, You are inflating the child activity two times

Comment: That's absolutely true, I thought about it, But i am forced to inflate the first time to be able to set the data-binding variable and I don't know actually how to inflate the mBinding to the frameLayout. i can extend the setContentView in the base activity to accept two types of passed parameters and then i will be able to pass mBinding .getRoot() but how to inflate it tothe frameLayout??

Comment: call `mRelativeLayout.addView(inflatedViewFromParameter, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))`

Comment: @MustafaShahoud add your inflatedView to Relative Layout using .addView() and pass Layout params as shown in above comment

Comment: @MustafaShahoud Or if you want to add to FrameLayout, then do `addView(inflatedViewFromParameter, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))`

Comment: @ Zohaib Amir Thanks Bro, You made my night,  I have accepted your answer and upvoted it.